# Checking index for series object in python

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have code like this:

```
indexes = [alphabet.index(x) for x in firstletters]
```

I want to change `alphabet.index(x)` for a Series object I created which contains the alphabet as well, but with ASCII characters for each letter as indexes. Can you give me a hint how to do it?

I tried doing this in this way but this does not work.

```
indexes = [alphabet1.Series.index(x) for x in firstletters]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a Series object like this...

```
>>> s = pd.Series(list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))
>>> s
>>>
0     a
1     b
... 22 rows omitted ...
24    y
25    z
dtype: object
```

...you can do this:

```
>>> firstletters = 'hello'
>>> indexes = [df[df == x].index[0] for x in firstletters]
>>> indexes
[7, 4, 11, 11, 14]
```